# Game development, beginner's advice for Java/Scala programmer

Tags: java, scala, game-engine

Hi I am planning to participate in [Thousand Year Game Design Challenge](http://danielsolisblog.blogspot.com/2010/12/thousand-year-game-design-challenge.html). I am new to game development. I know Java/Scala very well.

I was thinking if anyone could share advice/learning of their experience as a game developers. How do I start? Is there any open source tool that will make you move fast? Which is better to use Java or Scala to develop a game?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO, if you can choose between Java and Scala and have no further constraints, then always choose Scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some well-known libraries and frameworks, have a look at [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) and [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) in particular.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try http://processing.org/

Comment: That's not Java / Scala, is it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something a little more pure-Scala, have a look at [Sgine](http://www.sgine.org/) -- from at least one of the developers of jMonkeyEngine.  I don't think they consider it to be production-ready yet, but it might be fun to play with at least.